# Embed Tableau in Markdown (Hugo Academic)

Tags: markdown, tableau-api, hugo

I am trying to embed some Tableau dashboards into my new blog, which is built in Hugo Academic via RStudio Blogdown. I include the code, and, although my site renders fine (no errors), the dashboard never shows up - just whatever text I included before/after it.

Here is the complete embed code (a mix of HTML and Javascript):

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1581355801663' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'>
<img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;St&#47;StudentEnrollmentDashboardPortfolio&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a>
</noscript>
<object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> 
<param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> 
<param name='site_root' value='' />
<param name='name' value='StudentEnrollmentDashboardPortfolio&#47;Dashboard1' />
<param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
<param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;St&#47;StudentEnrollmentDashboardPortfolio&#47;Dashboard1&#47;1.png' /> 
<param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
<param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
<param name='display_count' value='yes' /></object></div>                
<script type='text/javascript'>
                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1581355801663');                    
var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                   
 if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='1000px';vizElement.style.height='827px';} else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='1000px';vizElement.style.height='827px';} 
else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='727px';}                     
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                <
/script>
```

Comment: It's not a full solution, but this works as a substitute:

```<div style="align: center; margin-left: -150px;">
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/StudentEnrollmentDashboardPortfolio/Dashboard1?:showVizHome=no&:embed=true" width="1000px" height="900px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config.toml file, go to the "Configure the Markdown Renderer" section. Turn unsafe to true. It should solve your issue. I struggled with the same issue for hours.

```
# Configure the Markdown renderer.
[markup]
  defaultMarkdownHandler = "goldmark"
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true  # Enable user to embed HTML snippets in Markdown content.
```

Comment: Thanks. What theme are you using? I did not see this option for Hugo Academic. In my config.toml, I have "Black Friday Rendering" (not Goldmark) and no options for that. I can already use HTML snippets, but advanced ones with javascript get stripped out. The iframe example above works, though.

Comment: I'm using the default theme of academic.
Try this:
https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic